# MySQL find records between open time and close time

Tags: mysql

We've a multiple restaurants open and closed times, on specific day(s) of the week. We have restaurants that open overnight. for example restaurants timing is `(10:00 AM Monday - 05:00 AM Tuesday)`

I am trying the following SQL query. But record return count is zero.

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE `restaurants_hours` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `day_of_week` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `open_time` time NOT NULL,
  `close_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `restaurants_hours` (`id`, `shop_id`, `day_of_week`, `open_time`, `close_time`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'sunday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00'),
(2, 1, 'monday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00'),
(3, 1, 'tuesday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00'),
(4, 1, 'wednesday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00'),
(5, 1, 'thursday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00'),
(6, 1, 'friday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00'),
(7, 1, 'saturday', '10:00:00', '05:00:00');
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT id, open_time, close_time, day_of_week FROM restaurants_hours WHERE
(((close_time > open_time) AND (FIND_IN_SET('thursday', day_of_week)) 
AND (open_time <= '12:40') AND (close_time >= '12:40') )
OR
((close_time <= open_time) AND (FIND_IN_SET('wednesday', day_of_week)) AND (close_time > '12:40')))
```

Comment: can you show which result you want exactly to that data?

Comment: @nbk I just want which record is match. Mysql Query return the match row. You can check this [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/809d656/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/809d656/3). When I pass night time its return row, But when I passed restaurant day timing query return count zero.

Comment: I suggest you add columns `open_day` and `close_day` and remove `day_of_week`. Then you'll be able to set these as `sunday` `10:00:00` - `monday` `05:00:00` and your query becomes much simpler. Right now there's an assumption built into your data that isn't obvious that close day != open day if the close time < open time. EDIT: it looks like you are wanting a single row per day per shop_id, right (so each shop would have 7 or fewer rows [if they're closed on X day]  in this table? If that's the case maybe my suggestion isn't valid.

Comment: @Strawberry I just trying to do get open restaurants between current date. We have a many restaurants. Restaurants have open and close timing within week. For example, `10:00 AM - Monday` Restaurant is open and close on `05:00 AM Tuesday`. When I run query with current time I just want get back is restaurant open or close.

Comment: If you think of it as "open periods" instead of "open days" then my suggestion makes sense and the logic is easier. Then your query can become `SELECT id, open_day, open_time, close_day, close_time FROM restaurants_hours
WHERE
  ((open_day = 3 AND open_time <= '16:45:00') OR (open_day < 3))
  AND ((close_day = 3 AND close_time >= '16:45:00') OR close_day > 3);` for finding open restaurants as of Wednesday 4:45pm. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5058c7/2 for a working example.

Comment: @Strawberry I means to say that when any time click on radio button the button name is `Open Restaurants`, I want run query and return only open restaurant by customer current time.

Comment: @Strawberry what type of example do you required?

Comment: @Strawberry Mostly restaurants opening timing AM to AM next day. for example restaurant open on Monday he will be closed on Tuesday. I show on top database structure. There have define `day_of_week column` and `open_time` and `close_time` columns. For example on website I have 2 radio filters Open and Close, When any one click on Open.  Query find open restaurant from table `restaurants_hours` and someone click on Close. Query find out closed restaurants from `restaurants_hours` table.

Comment: I can see we're not getting anywhere. Good luck.